# Fastest Way to send Data from Android to Server?

Tags: android, web-services, file-upload, data-transfer

I want to send image and text data from Android phone to a Server. i am new plz suggest me the best and easy way to do this task. Server is running a java web service and i will be getting the data from server and also sending the data to server. Thanks

Comment: Without any further information this question can't be answered.

Comment: What you have tried? What you have searched?

Comment: my application will capture an image and will send that image to a Server. now i am not sure how to send this image file along with some necessary information to a server. information will be stores in Database.

Comment: @LalitPoptani .. i have seen different methods to do this 1.using JSON  2.Embedding through URL   3.Using Sockets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your server is already there,  you will have to use  protocol it can uderstand - also SOAP, REST or whatever it uses.  So no choice for you.

If you are deigning client-server interacton with android application,  you may consider network socket communuication which has less overhead as webservices.

Comment: Can u please elaborate. my Server will be running web service all the time because i also want a two way communication between android and Server

Comment: There is no two way communication -  only request from your app and response to it.  And you already choosed your server architecture - so use webservice on client side.  Your only choice is concrete implementation ( there are differences, but not that much )